# Ionic iOS Build Succeeds but when trying to emulate the app doesn't appear in emulator

Tags: ios, bash, cordova, ionic-framework

As the title suggests, my Ionic iOS build succeeded, however, when I emulate it, the iOS emulator comes up except my app is not loaded on to there.

This is the error message:

```
2015-05-04 08:37:05.108 xcodebuild[45167:2385652]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-7536/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener.m:79
Details:  Running against an old version of MobileDevice; some interaction with proxied devices may be unavailable.
Object:   <DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener: 0x7f83cc87fad0>
Method:   -listenerThreadImplementation
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f83cc86c010>{number = 2, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

Comment: did you try running from Xcode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `ionic run ios` instead of `ionic run` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: woah! It works now, I was actually doing ionic emulate ios. They must have updated the cli since then. Thank you!